# Storing BlobKey in DataStore with app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

So I decided to rewrite my image gallery because of the new high performance image serving thing. That meant using Blobstore which I have never used before. It seemed simple enough until I tried to store the BlobKey in my model.

How on earth do I store reference to a blobstorekey in a Model? Should I use string or should I use some special property that I don't know about? I have this model

```
class Photo(db.Model):
 date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
 title = db.StringProperty()
 blobkey = db.StringProperty()
 photoalbum = db.ReferenceProperty(PhotoAlbum, collection_name='photos')
```

And I get this error: Property blobkey must be a str or unicode instance, not a BlobKey

Granted, I am a newbie in app engine but this is the first major wall I have hit yet.
Have googled around extensively without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a db.StringProperty() you need to use db.blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty (I think)

I'm still trying to figure this thing out as well, but thought I'd post some ideas.

Here are the reference pages from Google:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobReferenceProperty

Comment: I'm going to work on this part over the labor day weekend... that is if my wife doesn't through the laptop out the window (getting married on saturday!).

Answer (score 11):

The following works for me.  Note the class is blobstore.blobstore instead of just blobstore.

Model:

```
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import blobstore

class Photo(db.Model):
  imageblob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

Set the property:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    entity = models.db.get(self.request.get('id'))
    entity.imageblob = blob_info.key()
```

Get the property:

```
image_url = images.get_serving_url(str(photo.imageblob.key()))
```